# Derivative of Definite Integral/ Isolating a Function under a Definite Integral.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I am currently trying to model a Brushed DC Motor with a Drive Brake Motor driver (which controls motor speed (via PWM), and am having an issue solving for angular acceleration.

The differential equation for a DC motor is as follows:

PWM high: $sign(u)V = Ri(t) + K\omega$ **(1)**; where $sign(u)$ is the direction the voltage is being applied (counter clockwise or clockwise), V is the supply voltage, R is resistance, i(t) is current, K is a motor torque constant, and $\omega$ is motor rotational speed.

PWM low: $0 = Ri(t) + K\omega$ **(2)**

Inductance can be neglected in this case, and is not included in the aformentioned DE's.

I have read that an "average" differential equation can be used in replace of both of these:

$sign(u)V = Ri_{avg} + K\omega$ ; where $i_{avg}$ **(3)** is the average current over the period of the PWM.

Furthermore, there is also the following inertial relation:

$Ki(t) = J\alpha(t) + b \omega(t)$ **(4)**; where J is the moment of inertia of the motor shaft, b is the viscous friction coefficient of the motor, and $\alpha(t)$ and $\omega(t)$ are the angular acceleration and velocity of the motor shaft.

In order to get an equation for average current, I solved for $i(t)$ in **(4)**, and took an integral over the time of the PWM period, and divided by said period:

$i_{avg} = \frac{\int\limits_{\tau - \delta t}^{\tau} (\frac{J}{k}\alpha(t) + \frac{b}{k}\omega(t))dt}{\delta t}$ **(5)**; where $\delta t$ is the PWM period.

My reasoning behind the upper and lower limits of integration is that the summation I am doing always needs to be the last few samples of current, so having the lower bound always being $\delta t$ behind the current time accomplishes this.

I believe this can be simplified to:

$i_{avg} = \frac{J}{k\delta t}\int\limits_{\tau - \delta t}^{\tau} \alpha(t)dt + \frac{b}{k\delta t}\int\limits_{\tau - \delta t}^{\tau} \omega(t)dt$ **(6)**

Plugging **(6)** into **(3)** and isolating the $\alpha$ integral yields:

$\int\limits_{\tau - \delta t}^{\tau} \alpha(t)dt = \frac{\delta tkVsign(u)}{JR} - \frac{b}{J}\int\limits_{\tau - \delta t}^{\tau} \omega(t)dt - \frac{\delta tk^2}{JR}\omega(t)$ **(7)**

In order to actually use this model in Simulink, I believe it requires me isolate $\alpha(t)$; so my question is **how would I go about doing this with my definite upper and lower bounds both being related to $\tau$?**. I understand that taking the derivative of an integral yields just the function within the integral, and similarly for definite integrals, I believe the $\int\limits_{\tau - \delta t}^{\tau} \alpha(t)dt$ would yield $\alpha(\tau) - \alpha(\tau - \delta t)$. **I believe this is correct, and please correct me if I am wrong**. The $\omega$ integral would be simplified in a similar manner.

Furthermore, if I am taking the derivative ($\frac{d}{d\tau}$) of **(7)**, I believe this would set the $\frac{\delta tkVsign(u)}{JR}$ term equal to 0, as k, $\delta t$, V, J, and R are all constant. This term going to 0 doesn't seem to make sense to me, as V is the input to the system. Without voltage being represented, I have seemingly no input.

I suppose $sign(u)$ should really be $sign(u(\tau))$, so when taking its derivative, as long as $\frac{d}{d\tau}u(\tau) \neq 0$, voltage would still be represented.

With that being said, $sign(u)$ simply represents the direction the voltage is being applied, and is constant for large periods of time.

**This model without the voltage term just seems wrong; it seems to imply that motor acceleration is independent of the voltage applied to the motor**. **Does anyone have any suggestions to maybe something I have done wrong or incorrect assumptions? Does the voltage term being 0 sound weird to anyone else?**

**Finally, if anything I have done is fundamentally flawed, please tell me.**

I truly appreciate anyones reponse or feedback in this manner.

Thank you very much for your time,
-Dakota

Comment: When taking the derivative of an integral, you use [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule?useskin=vector) which I think you have done correctly. You find a relation between $\alpha(t)$ and $\alpha(t-\delta t)$, since this isn't the `complete' solution for $\alpha(t)$ it is not clear whether one should expect certain parameters in it or not (as you wonder for the voltage)